# pen and paper multiplication

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

I'm writing a program that does pen and paper multiplcation. I'm using 2 nested for loops to multiply over the 2d array of long values. I think add the last character to the workspace then add the first digits as the carry.

- How can I get it so that when the inner loop has finished executing, it creates a zero in the first column of the next set of numbers. Then if it's the second time, add two zeros etc etc, incrementing the number of zeros by one each time. When I get this working, I can then just add down the array.

Output:

```
    84882000000000000000
    26228000000000000000
    92946000000000000000
    68664000000000000000
```

Code:

```
     //set up temporary 2d array for working rowcount of array with be equal to length of numberTwo[]
        long[][] workspaceArray = new long[numberTwo.length][20]; //columncount is arbitrary

        long carry = 0;
        //int u = 0;
        //for every number in the bottom row

        for (int i = numberTwo.length-1, rowNum = 0; i >= 0; i--, rowNum++){

            for (int j = numberOne.length-1, columnNum = 0; j >= 0; j--, columnNum++){
                //System.out.println("Multiplying: "+numberTwo[i]+" and "+numberOne[j]);
                long value;

                if (carry == 0){
                    value = numberTwo[i]*numberOne[j];
                }else{
                    value = numberTwo[i]*numberOne[j]+carry;
                }
                //System.out.println("A "+value);
                long numberForWorkspace = extractLast(value);
                System.out.println("adding "+numberForWorkspace+" to the workspace at "+i+" "+j);
                workspaceArray[rowNum][columnNum] = numberForWorkspace; //not lining up properly, pass j into func
                //carry = extractAllButLast(value);


            }


        }
        for (int k = 0; k < workspaceArray.length; k++){
            for (int h = 0; h < workspaceArray[k].length; h++){
                System.out.print(workspaceArray[k][h]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION

Updated: I tried doing it this way but I seem to get index out of bounds exception after i run through a few indexes.

```
int numberOfZeros = 0;
        for (int i = numberTwo.length-1, rowNum = 0; i >= 0; i--, rowNum+=numberOfZeros){

            for (int j = numberOne.length-1, columnNum = 0; j >= 0; j--, columnNum++){
                System.out.println("Multiplying: "+numberTwo[i]+" and "+numberOne[j]);
                long value;

                if (carry == 0){
                    value = numberTwo[i]*numberOne[j];
                }else{
                    value = numberTwo[i]*numberOne[j]+carry;
                }
                //System.out.println("A "+value);
                long numberForWorkspace = extractLast(value);
                System.out.println("adding "+numberForWorkspace+" to the workspace at "+rowNum+" "+columnNum);
                workspaceArray[rowNum][columnNum] = numberForWorkspace; 
                //carry = extractAllButLast(value);


            }
            numberOfZeros++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to add a line after the closing brace of the inner loop - something like

```
if(workspaceArray.size > i + 1){  //Avoids ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
   workspaceArray[i+1][0] = 0;
}
```

Comment: More explictly, after the inner for loop  has executed the first time for the next row I want the first value to be 0 and everything else added onto the end of that (not overwriting the first index with a 0). Then for the second row I want it to be two zeros in the front and then add the numbers.

Comment: Ok so maintain a count of the number of iterations of the loop which starts at 0 and gets updated at the end of the inner loop.  Outside the loop take the next array and add that many 0s as required.  You'll then need to add this number to your other indexes

Comment: Thanks, Tried it, updated original post, getting indexoutofbounds :E

Comment: Just spotted it - change your for condition to:         for (int i = numberTwo.length-1, rowNum = numberOfZeros; i >= 0; i--, rowNum++){.  The problem is that you are adding the number of zeros to rowNum n times rather than just once!